# Sorting in Elastic Search by defined type

Tags: php, jquery, elasticsearch

I have this request to elastic service.

Url callback is:

```
GET 
/es-main/Project,ProjectStage,Task,TaskComment,TicketComment,Client,User,Attachment/_search
```

How to add Sort improvement requirements that the results were in sequence as they are embedded in the URL + score? Now alphabetically by type. Example first is type Project, second is ProjectStage, etc...

Thanks all for answers...

```
GET /es-main/Project,ProjectStage,Task,TaskComment,TicketComment,Client,User,Attachment/_search 
Array
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [query_string] => Array
                (
                    [query] => *a*
                    [analyzer] => hunspell_cs
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => name
                            [1] => description
                            [2] => tags.name
                            [3] => text
                            [4] => email
                            [5] => filename
                        )

                )

        )
    [from] => 0
    [size] => 10
    [sort] => Array
        (
            [_type] => ASC
            [_score] => DESC
        )

    [aggs] => Array
        (
            [CountByType] => Array
                (
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => _type
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't look at the order of the types in your URL. You need to manipulate the scores so that you get that order.

Comment: now sorting by _type ASC and _score DESC, but i need sort in _type by sort in types. There is no problem to add these types to ordering. This types i have in array.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i have added in document _is_Project = 1, _is_ProjectStage = ,_is_Task = 1, etc...
and set ordering to:

```
order: {
 '_is_Project': {'unmapped_type': 'long'}, // first
 '_is_ProjectStage': {'unmapped_type': 'long'}, // second
 '_is_Task': {'unmapped_type': 'long'}, // third - etc...
 '_score': 'DESC'
}
```